# Can someone help me figure out this music theory KEY finding question

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, key, musicology

Messing around Sunday I came up with a song that has the following Chord Progression. I'm just learning music theory and am having trouble on identifying the key.

The chord progression is:

C7 D7 F7 E7 C7 D7 F7 G7

I'm curious because I'm trying to see how this progression fit's into they key the modes and the scales it would work with.

I have used the reverse key finders and come up with Gm or Am but don't see how it fit's into those keys in terms of scales.

Thanks Everyone,

Kevin

Answer (score 3):

The chords don't actually fit in any particular key, but there is a tonal center. I didn't play it yet, but I feel like that would be C, so the progression would be in C major, in a colorful way of course.

The second block of 4 chords is kind of common, contains a perfect cadence at the end (F G C), and the D-F movement is oftenly used too, in general to approach G (maybe a V-I with interpolation of VIIb borrowed from parallel minor scale?). The G, though, contains a 7th that pulls back to C.

In the first block, I think the E7 causes a little a surprise, as one would expect a G, as I said. The F E C then, could be a deceptive cadence, since you would expect a Am after E, but instead, you use it's relative, C.

So, you can see that despite momentary feelings of G major and A minor, all blocks end up returning to C major, so IMO that would be the key. The fact that all chords have 7ths just makes it all feel more bluesy.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I was struggling between G and Am, the C tonal center makes sense and gives me something else to study more on.